# Magento 2 Custom Option File Upload gets 404 when trying to download from order view

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, paypal-express, download, sales-order-view

We have a custom option on a product to upload an image with the product (business cards).

The order is placed just fine and the link to download the image is on the order in the backend.

**When I click on the link to download the image it takes me to a 404 page.**

***Here are the items I have checked to try to track down this issue:***

> 1. Check permissions to media folder and it is owned by web user and has
>    777 permissions for all sub-folders and files
> 2. Placed a test order using the zero subtotal checkout payment method and everything worked fine
> 3. Placed a test order using the paypal express checkout payment method and get the 404 error message on the file again.
> 4. I checked the database table quote_item_option for the option_id list in the URL and it doesn't exist for the paypal express payment
>    method orders.
> 5. I checked the /pub/media/custom_options/quote folder and the files exist under the first two letters of the file name and I am able
>    figure out which image goes with which order based on the dimension of
>    the image. These files exist for all orders no matter the payment
>    method.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I am at a lost.

> ***Here is the URL for a test paypal express payment***
>
> https://pc.drivemarketing.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/86165/key/01a76f8e26cb34a30854/

Comment: Is this only on Paypal Express? I had a similar issue forced us to get rid of paypal express :X

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6384 maybe related

Comment: That sounds just like it! Did you try the fix mentioned in that github issue?

Comment: Not yet... its just a headache with testing so I'm leaving Paypal express disabled for now. Sometime down the road I'll try it